# Can't connect Watson IoT Platform to Cloudant

Tags: watson-iot

I've been trying for some time now to connect my Watson IoT Platform to a Cloudant database as a Historian service.

I´ve followed instructions from a variety of tutorials available but one service never appears as an possible connection to the other, or as an extension.

Here is one tutorial that I've tried https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/cloudant_connector.html#cloudant_main

This is my resources dashboard. I've read that I should create both services in the same space (projetos.frondizi@gmail.com / dev), but when I'm creating the Cloudant service it won't let me choose.

[image: Resources dashboard]

Any insights on how to connect these services?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an alias from the Cloudant service so that the IoT Service can recognize it. That can be done via cf console, as such:

1) Install cf
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/ibmcloud/download_cli.html#install_use

2) Run below commands:

ibmcloud login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net

ibmcloud target --cf-api https://api.ng.bluemix.net -o projetos.frondizi@gmail.com -s dev

ibmcloud resource service-alias-create iot-cloudat-alias --instance-name 'Cloudant-zw'

If successful, you can see the alias under the IoT service in the IBM Cloud dashboard.

3) Launch the IoT Dashboard and setup extension

Comment: Oh God, can´t thank you enough! I haven't seen any mention at all to the necessity of creating an alias anywhere in the documentation. This is for a freelance job and I've almost got past my deadline.

Comment: Now I can connect, and it shows "connected" everywhere. But actually no database has been created in Cloudant, and when I try to configure it from the WIoTP it shows "binding..." and nothing happens... Is it supposed to take this long? Its been a hour... I can post this in another question if you'd like. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, I've posted another question here, if you could help again I´d appreciate very much. Thanks again! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316539/watson-iot-platform-stuck-in-binding-state-connecting-to-cloudant