# Watson IoT Platform stuck in "Binding" state connecting to Cloudant

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, cloudant, watson-iot

I've been trying for a few days now to use Cloudant as my Watson IoT Platform´s Historian service, but still no success.

I've finally managed to connect them with help I got here: [Can't connect Watson IoT Platform to Cloudant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275906/cant-connect-watson-iot-platform-to-cloudant), so I was able to set the bucket interval, and so on.

But though I can see them as connected in each "Connections" tab, no databases were created, and I can´t see Cloudant when I'm setting up my board Card.

When I get to the Extensions page on WIoTP and click on the gear button it appears to be stuck in a "binding" state as displayed in this screenshot.

Can anyone put a light in this?

Thanks!

[image: ![Screenshot]

Comment: when you have setup the extension, did you get a pop-up(some times a new tab) asking for authorization and was the authorization successful?

Comment: Yes, I got the pop-up and a “Authorizarion successful, you can now close this tab” message

Comment: what browser did you use? tried firefox and worked fine for me

Comment: Hi Idan, just to tell you that I deleted everything and rebuilt from scratch with you alias advice and finally got it working, thank you again!

Comment: glad that worked for you thanks for letting me know